# difficulties with files in python

Tags: python, file

For a homework assignment I have a filepath called P, and a string called S which is equal to 'parrot', I need to search P for S and output the number of times S appears. I cannot use regexs.

this is my code:

```
matches = []
matches2 = []
def file_reading(P, S):

  file1 = open(P, 'r')
  matches.append(S)
  file1.close()  
for S in P:
  matches2.append(S)

print (len(matches2))
```

The output should be 3 but this only outputs 1, can someone point me in the right direction? if more details are needed let me know and I will edit them in.

Comment: Please post valid code. Not only is your indentation incorrect, `append` requires an argument and `close()` doesn't take one, so running this would do nothing other than return TypeErrors.

Comment: Check out [the documentation on file reading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).  In particular, look at `f.read()` function.

Comment: Your example is indeed not complete since you do not show use the contents of the file. Please show those contents.

Comment: I dont know the contents of the file they were not provided with the assignment, however S is 'parrot'.

Comment: Look at the code in your question. The indentation is still off.

Answer (score 0):

In order to search how many times S appears in P, you can simply do the following.

P = "/home/shan/shan/shan/editshanfile/exe"

S = "shan"

parts = P.split(S)

print (len(parts)-1)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file using given path **P**
2. Read the file into a variable
3. Search that variable for the target string **S**
4. Close the file
5. Print the output

Comment: I think the OP understood that much, even though you seem to skip over the "number of times" part of the question. But maybe you could point to the problems in the OP's code and suggest corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect string.count(string2) is what you're looking for:

```
>>> big_string = 'a' * 100 + 'parrot' + 'b' * 20 + 'parrot' + 'c' * 50 + 'parrot'
>>> len(big_string)
188
>>> big_string.count('parrot')
3
>>>
```